# Why does reduction using sodium borohydride require a protic solvent?

Tags: organic-chemistry, organic-reduction

Recently, I was looking at the chapter on chemoselectivity in Clayden et al.'s Organic Chemistry (2nd ed.). On p. 530, it is mentioned that sodium borohydride reduction only occurs in protic solvents or in the presence of electrophilic metal ions, such as $\ce {Li+}$ and $\ce {Mg^2+}$ while the more powerful reducing agent lithium aluminium hydride does not require protic solvents. Why is that the case?

**Reference**

Clayden, J., Greeves, N., & Warren, S. (2012). Organic Chemistry (2nd ed.). New York : Oxford University Press Inc.

Comment: Principally solubility. Sodium borohydride is essentially insoluble in aprotic solvents.

Comment: @Waylander What about the need for the ions? These ions help to increase polarity of solvent, increasing the solubility of NaBH4?

Comment: Li and Mg cations act as Lewis acids coordinating to carbonyl oxygen, Na is much weaker in this respect.

Comment: Apparently, THF (a non-protic solvent) can also be used to conduct reductions with $\ce {NaBH_4}$, according to this: https://commonorganicchemistry.com/Common_Reagents/Sodium_Borohydride/Sodium%20Borohydride.htm#:~:text=NaBH4%20is%20usually%20used%20in,to%20give%20the%20respective%20borates.

Comment: As Mithoron states a labile Lewis acid is needed in the reaction similar to the role of Mg++ in a Grignard; Na+ is not quite up to the job in NaBH4.

Answer (score 6):

The roles of a protic solvent and lithium and magnesium salts can be tied together in their role as electrophiles—and they impact both solubility and reactivity.

**Protic Hydrogen's evil twin**

Sodium borohydride may require (or at least favor) protic solvents for good solubility, but [lithium borohydride is soluble up to several percent in diethyl ether[1]](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00853610). The presence of lithium ions, as well as protic hydrogen, appears to enhance the solubility of sodium borohydride, and we can expect magnesium with its diagonal-relationship similarity to lithium to do the same.

Among ions that are reasonably stable in most solvents, borohydride is unique in having hydrogen with a significant negative partial charge. With that comes boron-hydrogen bonding orbitals that are relatively strongly concentrated on the hydrogen atoms and relatively high in energy levels. Thus by both electrostatic and molecular-orbital renderings of hydrogen bonding, the hydridic hydrogens can serve as relatively good electron donors for hydrogen bonding. This interaction between hydridic and protic hydrogen in described for a magnesium borohydride-ammonia complex in Yan et al[[2](https://doi.org/10.1021/acsaem.0c01599)]. Hence the preference of borohydride for protic solvents. Lithium and magnesium ions, whose hydride salts have greater covalent character than hydrides of heavier alkali or alkaline earth metals, can also serve as electron acceptors as well. Thereby borohydride ion is drawn into solution by protic hydrogen, lithium ions or magnesium ions.

**Both ends against the middle**

In [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/159755/17175) the role of magnesium ion is Grignard reactions is described. This ion acts as an electrophile, attaching to the oxygen and polarizing the carbonyl group and thus assisting the nucleophilic attack. Magnesium ion from a salt (e.g., $\ce{MgCl2}$}, lithium from a salt (e.g.,$\ce{LiCl}$) or organolithium compound (e.g., $\ce{R2CuLi}$), or a proton transferred from a protic solvent, can have similar effects in making a carbonyl group more reactive.

**References**

1. Mikheeva, V.I., Troyanovskaya, E.A. Solubility of lithium aluminum hydride and lithium borohydride in diethyl ether. Russ Chem Bull 20, 2497–2500 (1971). https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00853610
2. Yigang Yan, Jakob B. Grinderslev, Mathias Jo̷rgensen, Lasse N. Skov, Jo̷rgen Skibsted, and Torben R. Jensen. "Ammine Magnesium Borohydride Nanocomposites for All-Solid-State Magnesium Batteries". ACS Appl. Energy Mater. 2020, 3, 9, 9264–9270.https://doi.org/10.1021/acsaem.0c01599

Comment: *"Thus by both electrostatic and molecular-orbital renderings of hydrogen bonding, the hydridic hydrogens can serve as relatively good electron donors for hydrogen bonding."* — This is interesting: do you have a source that goes more into detail about this? [I'm sorry if it's the reference above, I don't have access any more.]

Comment: @orthocresol note my new reference.