Why does LiBH4 reduce esters while NaBH4 does not?
Clayden (pg 531) mentions that LiBH4 reduces esters, while NaBH4 does so, but at a very slow rate. Why?
Ref.: "Organic Chemistry" Second edition Jonathan Clayden Nick Greeves Stuart Warren 2012

related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/100444/why-does-reduction-using-sodium-borohydride-require-a-protic-solvent

In lithium borohydride, something pulls you along: the lithium.
In this answer the role of the positively charged magnesium in a Grignard reagent  as an electrophile is described. The reaction with the carbonyl group involves both the carbanion as a nucleophile (on the carbon) and the magnesium as an electrophile (on the oxygen) working together.
Lithium, with a fairly high charge density in its cation like magnesium, can act similarly as an electrophile on the carbonyl oxygen, polarizing the carbonyl group. As with the Grignard reaction with magnesium, this enhances the nucleophilic attack on carbon which, with borohydride ion as the nucleophile, is a hydride-transfer reduction. Replace the lithium with sodium, whose cation has less charge density, and you you don't get this electrophilic "pull" to drive the proposed nucleophilic attack on carbon forwards.
