# Why are Grignard reagents nucleophiles and not ambiphiles?

Tags: organic-chemistry, grignard-reagent, nucleophilicity

The way I see it, the -R (alkyl part) obtains a negative charge and the MgX obtains a net positive charge on bond dissociation. So a nucleophile and an electrophile both are obtained simultaneously. So why is Grignard reagent a nucleophile and not an ambiphile? Where am I wrong?

Comment: R- doesn't like being R- and MgX+ is fine with it.

Comment: There are some cases where the Mg cation binds to the Grignard substrate activating it or directing the nucleophilic attack, so you could say in these instances it is an ambiphile.

Comment: @Safdar Faisal would that mean R- would be a better nucleophile? Ready to get rid of that charge instantly?

Comment: @Waylander ah can you give me an example?

Comment: Exactly, the instability of R- is what acts as a driving force in most Grignard reactions

Comment: @Safdar Faisal oh I get it, thanks! Just one more doubt tho: by that logic , RCOO- is also a nucleophile, but the negative sign here is stable on the O, through resonance. So why does this act as a nucleophile?

Comment: @SaumyaChaturvedi  The Grignard addition to nitriles is arguably one.

Comment: @Waylander okay I'll check that out thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In fact a Grignard reagent reacting with, let us say, a ketone, is ambiphilic. However, the electrophilic component of the reaction, in which the positively charged magnesium combines with the carbonyl oxygen, does not figure into the organic product on workup. See [this answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/159755/17175).