# What determines whether a mechanism is nucleo/electrophillic addition/substitution?

Tags: nucleophilic-substitution, electrophilic-substitution

So I recognise what an electrophile and a nucleophile *is*, but not all mechanisms (that I know of at least) have one species substituting or adding. For example, propanone added to NaBH$_4$ has an initial step of a hydride (nucleophilic addition), and then a
H$^+$ being added to an O$^-$ (electrophilic addition).

I'm a bit wary of this example as the second step doesn't involve a carbon. So, another example would be the addition of HBr to ethene. The first step has the addition of H$^{\delta+}$ (electrophile) and then Br$^{-}$ being added as a nucleophile.

[This website](http://www1.biologie.uni-hamburg.de/b-online/library/newton/Chy251_253/Lectures/EAddition/Addition.html#:%7E:text=The%20first%20step%20involves%20addition,as%20an%20electrophilic%20addition%20reaction.) offers a solution by specifying that the rate determining step takes precedence, but I can't find anything to corroborate this

Comment: so what exactly is your doubt, is it like identifying which step occurs first or whether it is entirely an SN or EN mechanism reaction ?

Comment: The latter; (The site suggest it's to do with the rate determining step)

Comment: in the end it is the rate determining step and stability of intermediates formed which decides whether an SN or EN reaction occurs. Eg : in a tertiary halide E1 is most preferred, followed by SN1 and SN2 and E2 are almost negligible.

Comment: @PSR_123. Thanks. This answers my question

Comment: You know the difference between addition and substitution. Nucleophilic/electrophilic reactions are similar to redox reactions with reapect to reagents involve. There is always a reduction reaction when oxidation invoved. Similarly, there is always nucleophilic reaction when electrophilic reaction involved.

Comment: @PSR_123 your throwing around these mechanism schemes like these are supposed to be a universal truth. If anything, they are idealised model reactions and they don't happen in nature. The rate determining step approximation should also carefully viewed as a crude approximation. It only produces reasonable (not good) results of one (and only one) step is magnitudes faster than all (including side reactions) other steps. I find your comment counterproductive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reaction that is either a nucleophilic or an electrophilic addition/substitution is in fact *both* a nucleophilic and an electrophilic addition/substitution. Whatever a nucleophile combines with can also be called an electrophile that attacks the nucleophile; textbooks just adopt a single perspective.

We also have examples where the *same* reagent is both an electrophile and a nucleophile to different parts of the "substrate". [Grignard reactions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/159755/17175), in which the Grignard reagent has both a nucleophilic carbon atom and an electrophilic magnesium atom, are one such example.